# Looking for a term that represents open, high, low, close, volume

Tags: stocks, price, terminology

I'm writing a little test app this weekend and I'm trying to come up with a name that represents this data:

```
open price
close price
high price
low price
time open
time close
volume
```

So far I've considered calling this group of data a "tick" or a "candle". Not sure about either of those options. What's the right term to describe this data?

Comment: Not sure how relevant time is, I'm used to just 'date'. I'd call this daily stock data. I may be wrong, but I've never heard a specific term for this data set.

Comment: You can use OHLC but that will not include the time and volume

Comment: I'll suggest "price range"

Answer (score 3):

OHLC

is a term and acronym that represents much of that data

Comment: Is this pronounceable? Or do you just say the 4 letters?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer "Open High Low Close chart" is the only way I recall that being spoken in context where it is a personal preference to see OHLC in comparison to candlestick charts (which is a data visualization of OHLC as well), all literature on the other hand just says OHLC